# JQUERY прокрутка до элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть `button id='tmp'`.

И длинная страница всегда разной длины. Отступ снизу и сверху каждый раз разный при обновлении страницы.

Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке страницы до `button` кнопка нажималась?

Comment: Лёгким колдунством. Где Ваш код?

Comment: @Other, колдоВством!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, если нужно сказать иронично, то именно колдунство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var Down = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollingTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(window).length) {
            var thirdSection = parseInt($('#tmp').offset().top) - 100;

            if (scrollingTop > thirdSection) {
                if (Down == 0) {
                    $('#tmp').trigger("click");
                    Down = 1;
                }

            }

        }

    });
```